# Measure theory, product of $L^2$ functions, convergence in $L^1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

How can I prove this?

Let $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ and $g_n \to g$ in $L^2$. Then $f_n \cdot g_n \to f \cdot g$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Have you considered using Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Hölder's inequality and $f_n g_n - f g = (f_n - f) g_n + f (g_n - g)$.

Comment: I've tried Hölder's inequality but it didn't get me anywhere. Thank's for your tip, md2perpe. I could solve it now :)

Answer (score 5):

Note that using triangle inequality, you have
$$\|f_n\cdot g_n - f\cdot g\|_{L^1} = \|g_n \cdot (f_n-f) +f\cdot (g_n-g)\|_{L^1} \le \|g_n \cdot(f_n-f)\|_{L^1} + \|f\cdot (g_n-g)\|_{L^1}$$
Now Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to conclude.